# Finding Meat After 6 Hours

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, dairy, meat-and-milk

Suppose you wait 6 hours (or more) and then realize you have a small piece of meat stuck in your teeth:

- Do you have to remove it before eating dairy?
- [assuming you have to remove it] Do you have to wait any additional time, and/or rinse your mouth before eating dairy?

(six: assuming that's your *minhag*)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Orthodontics and period between eating fleischig and milchig](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/orthodontics-and-period-between-eating-fleischig-and-milchig)

Comment: The question itself isn't a duplicate, but the same answer applies to both questions.

Comment: @Yaakov Like peter said, [see here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). Basically, just because the answer is the same does not make it a duplicate. In their essence they are both completely separate questions. E.g. 1+1=2 and 3-1=2 duplicates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See @YDK's [answer to this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/orthodontics-and-period-between-eating-fleischig-and-milchig/7491#7491).

**Edit:**

> Summary: Definite particles must be removed after 6 hours (plus a
>   mouth rinse). Unknown particles are of no concern.

Answer (score 3):

the answer is no, one does not have to wait again. although the badei hashulchan quotes the haflaah as saying you do, its a mistake as the haflaah inside (yd 87) concludes that one **does not** have to wait. whichever reason one holds of why we wait after eating meat - neither will apply as there is no taam basar in your palate or throat with basar particles stuck in your teeth and after 6 hours the basar would already be pagum and not considered actual basar - like Rav shlomo zalman's hetter by false teeth - see [here](http://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5117) - echoing the psak of both the chasam and ksav sofer!

therefore one does not have to wait after finding meat stuck in their teeth after 6 hours

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara ([Hullin 105a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=105&format=pdf)) rules that meat stuck between the teeth is still considered meat:

> אמר ליה רב אחא בר יוםף לרב חםדא בשר שבין השינים מהו?‏
>
> קרי עליה "הבשר עודנו בין שיניהם"‏
>
> (My translation:) Rav Akha said to Rav Hasda, "What is the law of meat stuck between the teeth?" He answered him with a pasuk: "'the *meat* was still between their teeth (Bamidbar 11:33)'"

Rashi explains:

> Q: מי חשיב בשר שלא לאכול גבינה
>   עמו **עד שיטלנו**?‏
>
> A: אלמא מיקרי בשר

It seems from Rashi that it is assumed in the question that even if meat stuck between the teeth is considered meat, removing it would be enough to permit dairy consumption.

The [Ran](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37967&st=&pgnum=659) (last few lines of D"H **אמר**) specifically writes that removing the meat is enough and that additional waiting is not necessary, but suggests a cleaning of the palate first.